# python requests with proxy can't follow redirects

Tags: python, redirect, proxy, python-requests

```
s = requests.Session()
r_token = s.get('https://www.netflix.com/Login',
                                allow_redirects=False,
                                proxies=proxies,
                                headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().random},
                            )
```

I made a python request to netflix with a proxy and the results could not but if not using a proxy he could follow the redirect url

the final url should be https://www.netflix.com/[country-code]/Login

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `allow_redirects=True`, to follow redirects:

```
import logging, requests
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

#proxies = {'https': '144.217.161.149:8080'}
proxies={}
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.35 Safari/537.36'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://www.netflix.com/Login',
                                allow_redirects=True,
                                proxies=proxies,
                                headers={'User-Agent': ua},
                            )

print (r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Prints:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.netflix.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.netflix.com:443 "GET /Login HTTP/1.1" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.netflix.com:443 "GET /de-en/Login HTTP/1.1" 200 None
(200, 'OK')
```

The same behaviour should happen when you are using a proxy.
Netflix blocks/restricts access through proxy/vpn.